# Android app sets variables to default value after phone call

Tags: android, kotlin

I noticed a bug in my app where variables were being reset to their initial value after text messages and phone calls  - This error doesn't occur every time.

It is almost as if onCreate had been called again as the onResume and onStart methods only hold functions to bind to services and save co-ordinates for a floating button.

Is there any explanation for this? Has anyone else had this issue?

My app lifecycle methods as below

```
private var stopped = false
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    /* Bind to Service */
    if (!mBound){
        mBound = bindScanner(this,versionSDK, connection)
        mBound = true
        mService?.send(getMsg(MSG_CREATE))
    }
    if (stopped){
        stopped = false
        mService?.send(getMsg(MSG_CREATE))
    }
}
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    if(!stopped){
        stopped = true
        mService?.send(getMsg(MSG_DESTROY))
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    if(!stopped){
        stopped = true
        mService?.send(getMsg(MSG_DESTROY))
    }

    if (mBound){
        unbindService(connection)
        mBound = false
    }

    if (floatButton){
        val params = floatBTN?.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        val data : MutableMap<String,String> = mutableMapOf()
        data["X"] = params.leftMargin.toString()
        data["Y"] = params.topMargin.toString()
        if (myDb.updateRowData("floatbtn",data,"Activity", FLOAT_BTN_PK_VAL) == 0){
            data.clear()
            data["Activity"] = FLOAT_BTN_PK_VAL
            data["X"] = params.leftMargin.toString()
            data["Y"] = params.topMargin.toString()
            myDb.insertData("floatbtn",data)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your process was terminated while your app was in the background. This is perfectly normal and has been [a part of Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle) since the beginning.

Comment: It seems like this is the case, but I needed an explanation for when It occurs on my App. I wonder, is there a way to send the app back to it's starting screen when this occurs instead of the screen it was last on?

Comment: @RowanBerry: IIRC, there is nothing really automatic for this. Google would prefer that you use the saved instance state `Bundle` in order to hold onto enough identifiers that will allow you to restart where the user last was. You can send the app back to its starting screen yourself if you determine that some data is missing that you expect to exist (e.g., session ID tied to user authentication).